# Showing loading message while doing WMSGetFeatureInfo using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, getfeatureinfo

I have the following control in my page :

```
new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
        url: xxxxxx,
        name: 'infoControl',
        queryVisible: true,
        eventListeners: {
           getfeatureinfo: function (e) {
.
.
.}})
```

I want to show a "loading" message while doing the ajax call for WMSGetFeatureInfo.

How do I call my "loading" function the moment I click on the feature?

The event listener in the code above happens once the data returns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how to show loading mask while doing WMSGetFeatureInfo :

1. Create the loading mask (I've been using ExtJS)

`var mask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {msg:"Retrieving Info"});`

2. Declare The WMSGetFeatureInfo event listener and make it HIDE the mask:

   ```
    infoControl = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
        url: "xxxxxxx",
        infoFormat: "application/vnd.ogc.gml",
        name: "infoControl",
        maxFeatures: 5,
        queryVisible: true,
        eventListeners: {            
           getfeatureinfo: function (e) {
                mask.hide(); 
            // Your code handling the feature popups                    
            }
        }
    });
   ```
3. Attach "beforegetfeatureinfo" event to the control with showMask function

`infoControl.events.register("beforegetfeatureinfo", this, showMask);`

4. attach "nogetfeatureinfo" with hideMask function in case there were no features (you can also add some kind of alert here).

   `infoControl.events.register("nogetfeatureinfo", this, hideMask);`

Answer (score -1):

I use a very simple tool called NProgress. ( http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/  )

Simply load the javascript src and add the following line at the start

```
NProgress.start()

// your code here 

NProgress.done()
```

this works best if you have a single function to do your ajax request.

J

Comment: thank JSz , but this doesn't help in in my case because the challange was to call the loading mask right before the click event which I didn't know how to catch (now I do).
thank you for the response !

Comment: I knew how to show the loading , just didn't knew where is the event I need to call loading from ...